# How to fix "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set" for JavaFX project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I have created a JavaFX project in eclipse where I am keeping the Java code under src folder and the fxml files under resources folder. There are a few UI components which have no corresponding fxml files, e.g. a custom button.

When I try to import such components into the fxml files, I get the following error 
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.

I have looked at many issues with "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set" error, but could not find the same problem that I am facing.

For simplicity, I have reproduced the error with a smaller project, where the src folder tree structure is like this

```
     ── src
        ├── application
        │   └── Main.java
        ├── component
        │   └── RoundedButton.java
        ├── ui
        │   └── UIHomePage.java
        └── widget
            └── ListComboBox.java
```

and the resources folder tree structure is like this

```
     ── resources
        ├── ui
        │   └── UIHomePage.fxml
        └── widget
            └── ListComboBox.fxml
```

The Main.java contains the start method which is able to load the UIHomePage.fxml file, the controller for which is UIHomePage.java.

The RoundedButton.java extends javafx.scene.control.Button class and doesn't use a separate fxml file.

ListComboBox.java extends javafx.scene.layout.GridPane and uses ListComboBox.fxml as fxml resource.

The issue that I am facing is that when I am trying to load resources/ui/UIHomePage.fxml, it fails to figure out where ListComboBox is, because it somehow fails to locate src/widget/ComboBox.

I have both the src and the resources folders added as Source inside Java Build Path as well.

Main.java (start method code loading the fxml file UIHomePage.fxml only)

```
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("ui/UIHomePage.fxml"));
```

UIHomePage.fxml

```
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
    <?import component.RoundedButton?>
    <?import widget.ListComboBox?>

    <GridPane fx:controller="ui.UIHomePage" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" alignment="center">
        <GridPane GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="1" GridPane.halignment="CENTER" visible="true" vgap="10" hgap="10">
            <ListComboBox  fx:id="cityName" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" GridPane.columnSpan="2" GridPane.rowSpan="1"/>
            <RoundedButton fx:id="addButton"     GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="1" GridPane.rowSpan="1" text="Add Property"     defaultButton="true" onAction="#handleAddProperties"/>
        </GridPane>
    </GridPane>
```

UIHomePage.java

```java
    import widget.*;
    public class UIHomePage {
        @FXML private ListComboBox  cityName;
        @FXML
        public void initialize() throws Exception{
            cityName.setPrefWidth(GridPane.REMAINING);
        }
        @FXML
        protected void handleAddProperties(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
    }
```

ListComboBox.fxml

```
    <fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.GridPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
        <ComboBox fx:id="comboBox" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0"/>
    </fx:root>
```

ListComboBox.java

```java
    public class ListComboBox extends GridPane {
        @FXML
        private ComboBox<String> comboBox;
        public ListComboBox() {
            FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("widget/ListComboBox.fxml"));
            fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
            fxmlLoader.setController(this);
            try {
                fxmlLoader.load();
            } catch (IOException exception) {
                throw new RuntimeException(exception);
            }
        }
    }
```

RoundedButton.java

```java
    public class RoundedButton extends Button {
        public RoundedButton() {
            super();
            this.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 10; -fx-background-color: #eee8aa; -fx-text-fill: #8b4513; -fx-font-size: 3em; ");
        }
    }
```

I am hoping to get the UI to load with a custom combo box and a rounded button, but UIHomePage.fxml is unable to load ListComboBox (the custom combo box), and I keep getting the following error message

```
    javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/home/gangs/Programming/workspace/Java/TestProject/bin/ui/UIHomePage.fxml:7
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at application.Main.start(Main.java:18)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$161(LauncherImpl.java:863)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$174(PlatformImpl.java:326)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$172(PlatformImpl.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$173(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$48(GtkApplication.java:139)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2434)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
        at widget.ListComboBox.<init>(ListComboBox.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
        at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.constructValue(FXMLLoader.java:1009)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:746)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
        ... 17 more
```

One solution that I know will work is if I put all the fxml files under src folder, but that makes it difficult to manage the project as it grows. I want to retain this structure of separating the Java code and the fxml file under separate folders so that the code maintenance is easier in future.

Can someone please help me understand what is it that I missed here?

Comment: Note that you're not using the classloader to resolve the path in the constructor of `ListComboBox`. This means the path is interpreted as relative to the package of the `Class` object. You need to start the path with `/`, if you use `Class.getResource`: `new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/widget/ListComboBox.fxml")`

Comment: Thank you @fabian. I was finally able to get it working. I was trying to use the leading / in all the places where I was trying FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(), hence it was not working. Once I used it only in the individual widgets and not in the main resource loaded in the start program, it started working properly.